# Getting Pytest, Relative Import, and Patch.Object to Cooperate

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm having a hell of a time getting pytest, relative import, and patch to cooperate.

I have the following:

```
from .. import cleanup

class CleanupTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(cleanup, 'get_s3_url_components', MagicMock())
    @patch.object(cleanup, 'get_db_session', MagicMock(return_value={'bucket', 'key'}))
    @patch('time.time')
    def test_cleanup(self, mock_time, mock_session, mock_components):
        ...
```

I've tried a few variations.

1. The currently shown one. Pytest returns 'TypeError: test_cleanup() takes exactly 4 arguments (2 given)'. It's not recognizing the patch.objects, even though I'm pretty sure I'm using them correctly according to https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html
2. Changing the patch.objects over to simple patches causes them to throw 'no module named cleanup'. I can't figure out how to use patch with a relative import.

Edit: I'm using Python 2.7 in case that's relevant.

Comment: this looks correct -- perhaps you're using an old version of `pytest` which didn't recognize mocks?

Comment: I checked this. pytest does recognize other mocks I'm using just fine.

Comment: oh I see what it is now that I read closely, it has nothing to do with pytest -- let me write up an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this actually doesn't have anything to do with `pytest` and is merely the behaviour of the `mock` decorators

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch)

> If patch() is used as a decorator and `new` is omitted, the created mock is passed in as an extra argument to the decorated function

that is, because you're passing a replacement object the signature-mutation doesn't occur

For example:

```py
from unittest import mock

class x:
    def y(self):
        return 'q'

@mock.patch.object(x, 'y', mock.Mock(return_value='z'))
def t(x): ...


t()  # TypeError: t() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

Fortunately, if you're producing a `mock` object, you rarely need to actually pass in the `new` argument and can use the keyword options

For your particular example this should work fine:

```py
    @patch.object(cleanup, 'get_s3_url_components')
    @patch.object(cleanup, 'get_db_session', return_value={'bucket', 'key'})
    @patch('time.time')
    def test_cleanup(self, mock_time, mock_session, mock_components): ...
```

If you absolutely need them to be `MagicMock`s, you can use the `new_callable=MagicMock` keyword argument